# question about Gaussian map

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I have questions. Can anyone help me to get the idea or figure out this problem.
compute the Gaussian and mean curvature for torus.

notice
the metric for torus is
X(U,V)=((a+b cos(u))cos(v),(a+b cos(u))sin(v),b sin(u))
thanks

Comment: What metric are you putting on the Torus?

Comment: the metric for torus

Comment: There are infinitely many different such metrics.  For an example, just among embeddings which look like the "usual" torus, there is a double infinite family coming from choosing the two radii.  Different choices will give rise to different Gaussian and mean curvatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X(u,v) = ((a+b\cos(u))\cos(v), (a+b\cos(u))\sin(v), b\sin(u))$ is not a metric but rather the coordinates of an embedding of the torus into $\mathbb{R}^3$. So I will assume the metric you are considering is the metric induced on the torus by the ambient metric in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In this case there is a really neat way to calculate Gaussian and mean curvatures by first calculating the principal curvatures.

We can calculate the principal curvatures at a point $p$ by considering the curves given by the intersection of our torus with a plane that is perpendicular to the tangent plane at that point, $T_p$. The principal curvatures are then the maximum and minimum curvature that these curves can have. So, say we choose $p$ to be on the `outside' of the torus. If you imagine cutting the torus by a plane through this point and perpendicular to the tangent plane, you can see that the curve with the highest curvature we get in this manner is a circle with radius $a$ (I'm assuming that $a<b$) and the curve with the lowest curvature is a circle with radius $b$. The curvature of a circle of radius $r$ is given as $1/r$ so our principle curvatures are $1/a$ and $1/b$

We then get the Gaussian curvature as the product of the principal curvatures $K_p = 1/(ab)$  and the mean curvature as the average of the principal curvatures $H_p = \frac{1/a+1/b}{2}$.Notice however that both the Gaussian and the mean curvature will differ depending on which point $p$ we consider. (For example, consider what would happen if we took $p$ on the 'inner edge' of the torus). Frequently we are considering the torus with its `flat' metric (that is, a metric with zero Gaussian curvature) in which case the above method won't work, and we need to use a less intuitive method. If you are interested in this type of stuff, I highly recommend reading [this](http://books.google.co.za/books/about/Riemannian_Manifolds.html?id=ZRQgH7FQafgC&redir_esc=y) book by John Lee.